# How to get Adusers which are disabled of an defined company and shows the groups where this users are member of?

Tags: powershell

I have the following problem with my powershell script. With MemberOf I d'ont see all groups. I think the output is too long for the field.....

How can I resolve this problem? Any Help is welcome......

This is my script:

import-module activedirectory

get-aduser -filter {(company -eq "abc") -and (Enabled -eq $false)} -properties * | select company, samAccountName, MemberOf | Format-List

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to expand MemberOf

```
get-aduser -filter {(company -eq "abc") -and (Enabled -eq $false)} -properties * | select -expandproperty MemberOf
```

Example 2 in the link below uses this method.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

## Edited after below comments asking about foreach loop.

```
get-aduser -filter {(company -eq "abc") -and (Enabled -eq $false)} -properties * |
foreach {
    $props = [ordered]@{company = $($_.company)
                        samAccountName = $($_.samAccountName)
                        memberOf = $_ | select-object -ExpandProperty MemberOf
                       } #end props

    new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $props | format-list

} #end foreach
```

Hope this helps,

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: No worries. I thought you might be looking for that too. :) To do that, you will need to use a foreach loop. It gets a bit more complicated, you have to create a new object. http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/powershell/multiple-expands/ is a good example.

Comment: yes exactly, I have to do this with a foreach loop.......but I have no ideas how to do that......I will study your link........

Comment: If I get a chance, I will update my original answer with the foreach section.

Comment: thanks a lot.....looks great......where I have to put -join',' in the script?? I want to see all groups.....

Comment: Hi Dj, all the groups are in the script. They are all in the memberOf section, which is the bit that is expanded. If a user is in more than one group, the memberOf section has all of the members in it. You can change the | format-list at the end to change to an output that you would rather. All groups do get expanded though. Thanks, Tim.